# My Java Enterprise Application works just fine, but after I close NetBeans, open it again, and try to run it I keep getting this message

Tags: java, server, weblogic

Thanks in advance. When I try to run a simple application with two jsps, 2 java classes and one servlet I get the next message:

"build-impl.xml:1051: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details."

I am using Oracle WebLogic Server, and I've lately been having a problem...when I try to stop it by right-clicking on its name(Services tab and then Servers tab on NetBeans) and clicking on the stop button, I get a warning telling me the Oracle WebLogic Server couldn't be stopped.
I'm not sure if both problems are related.

I spent days looking for a solution, but didn't find one.

Comment: I already figured out the problem about stopping the server, but still have the problem of "The module has not been deployed...."

Comment: There are several answers to this error on forum. Many says to start IDE in admin mode